# Creating OpenAI Gym Environment from Map Data

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am just starting out with reinforcement learning and trying to create a custom environment with OpenAI gym. However, I am stumped with trying to create an environment (with roads and intersections) from map data, say Google Maps.

Would appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way that I have found would be to use [osmnx](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx) to have your map data ready in a graph format. It allows easy access of nodes that make up a street map in a graph or geopandas form. This data can then be used to drive the game logic. With regards to rendering, external rendering tools like PyGame can then be used.